# Implementation of tree command (DOS) on Linux in C

Tags: c, linux, directory-structure

I have to implement the *tree* command from DOS on Linux in C, so that when I run ./tree in a directory it prints it like this:

```
adir
   bdir
   cdir
      d.java
   edir
      fdir
         g.c
   hdir
```

My current code looks like this, but it's not even terminating when I run it, but I don't know how to fix it. Please help me solve it!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXLEN 256

char currentDir[256];
const char *pathname;

void tree(DIR *dp, struct dirent *dp1, char currentDir[256], int spaces);
void treeHelper(DIR *dp, struct dirent *dp1, char currentDir[256], int spaces);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

DIR *dp = opendir(".");
struct dirent *dp1 = readdir(dp);
int spaces = 0;
//char currentDir[256];
getcwd(currentDir, sizeof(currentDir));

while(dp1 != NULL) {
    if (strcmp(dp1->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dp1->d_name, "..") == 0) {
            continue;
    }

    if (dp1->d_type == DT_REG) {
            printf("%s\n", dp1->d_name);
    }


    if (dp1->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            tree(dp, dp1, currentDir, spaces);
    }
}
closedir(dp);
}

void tree(DIR *dp, struct dirent *dp1, char currentDir[256], int spaces) {

int i = 0;
strcat(currentDir, "/");
strcat(currentDir, dp1->d_name);

if((chdir(currentDir)) == -1){
        chdir("..");
        getcwd(currentDir, sizeof(currentDir));
        strcat(currentDir, "/");
        strcat(currentDir, dp1->d_name);

        for(i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
            printf ("   ");
    }
        printf("%s (subdirectory)\n", dp1->d_name);
        spaces++;
        treeHelper(dp, dp1, currentDir, spaces);
}

else {
    for(i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
            printf("   ");
    }
    printf("%s (subdirectory)\n", dp1->d_name);
    chdir(currentDir);
    spaces++;
    treeHelper(dp, dp1, currentDir, spaces);
}

}

void treeHelper(DIR *dp, struct dirent *dp1, char currentDir[256], int spaces) {
int i = 0;

while((dp1 = readdir(dp)) != NULL){

  if(strcmp(dp1->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dp1->d_name, "..") == 0)
    continue;

  //stat(currentPath, &statbuf);

  /*if(dit->d_type == 8 && argv[1] != NULL){*/
  if(dp1->d_type == DT_REG){
      for(i = 0; i < spaces; i++) {
          printf("   ");
      }
      printf("%s\n", dp1->d_name);
  }

  /*if(dit->d_type == 4)*/
  if(dp1->d_type == DT_DIR)
    tree(dp, dp1, currentDir, spaces);

}
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is your question? I only see statements of facts in your post but not a single question.

Comment: @FUZxxl I don't know how to fix the program to make it work. I know my code is pretty close to the solution, but I've been stuck on it for a long time now and simply can't figure it out.

Comment: Please describe the actual current behaviour of your program. And what have you done to debug it (surely you can at least find out where it is "stuck")? If you haven't already done so, suggest running your program in a debugger. Testing and debugging are essential developer skills and should not be outsourced to Stackoverflow lightly.

Comment: @Ana That's not a question either. Please ask a question.

Comment: The recursive call `tree(dp, dp1, currentDir, spaces);` simply calls `tree()` on the same directory.  Code needs to go to `tree(dp, dp1, pseudo_code_path_add(currentDir + dp1->d_name), spaces + 4);`

Comment: Use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html)

Answer (score 1):

> My current code looks like this, but it's not even terminating when I
>   run it…
>
> ```
> struct dirent *dp1 = readdir(dp);
> …
> while(dp1 != NULL) {
> ```

You call `readdir()` only once and then have an endless loop operating on the same *dirent* again and again. Change that to

```
struct dirent *dp1;
…
while (dp1 = readdir(dp))
{
```